# Server with thread per request vs pool of fixed threads

Tags: multithreading, server

Which one of these are better to implement in a server? I was wondering about the tradeoffs between spawning a thread per request versus using a worker pool consisting of a fixed number of threads, and how the performance will vary as the number of users increases. These are some questions that came up to my mind what I started to think about the way I want to implement my server.

Comment: What kind of server are we talking about? Is it CPU limited? Does it handle requests or send unsolicited data? Does it do lots of I/O? The details matter for decisions like this.

Comment: This server will handle user requests and send data back to users. I have read some tech articles, and from what I have read many of them use the pool, and I was wondering why.